# How to alleviate the development process through JIRA?

Tags: agile, scrum, jira

In our agile-scrum process, for each epic we are creating , we are creating automatically one user story that is related to that epic.

From that user story, we are creating automatically too, 4 subtasks:

- one design task
- one technical analysis task
- one product task
- one QA task.

The technical analysis task should explain what to do technically speaking in term of dev. However, we have one dev task that is creating a duplicate with the technical analysis.

Once, one of the subtasks are opened, we cannot closed them.

In term of automation, the ideas are good but the process can be improved.

My questions are the following:

- Do I need to have an epic and a user story,at the same time? I see them as duplicate but I maybe wrong
- Should I keep the technical analysis task when I already have a dev task that is created?
- Last but not least, should I close all the subtasks that are not used like design when they are no design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you not to automatically create anything.

The simplest approach is to do a task per story and to size your stories to 1 day.

Include unit testing as part of development, but only QA software releases. ie all the completed tasks.

Then you can put bugs back in as new tasks.

If you want to group many 1 day stories or lots of bugs/revisions together as the same feature, then you can start looking at epics.

But Its often best to just start working and sort out your PM software as you go. It allows you to figure out what works best for you without loading everyone down with admin tasks

Comment: hi @ewan, I do agree. I need to discuss that with the person who created that process. I learnt today that the process was built for one of our largest customer and we are using that for our internal use, which is similar to to receiving Shaquille O'Neal's jersey and me using it to play basketball...